# Xamarin Forms - slide text up behind image

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Within a grid I have an image then 2 stack layouts, one contains a row of icons and a button, and the one below contains a list of text items.
I have a function which, when the user click a button, the list animates upwards to effectively disappear, then downwards to reappear.

This works fine but the text is always visible over the image when animating up, is there a way to make the image always visible on top, so that it appears as if the text is sliding up behind the image?

Here is the code I use to animate the text stack:

```
public void ShowLess()
{
    TopLayout.TranslateTo(0, -(TopLayout.Bounds.Height + 60), 500, Easing.Linear);
    isIncreased = false;
}

public void ShowMore()
{
    TopLayout.TranslateTo(0, 0, 500, Easing.Linear);
    isIncreased = true;
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid BackgroundColor="#ede8db">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="47.5*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="47.5*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ratio:ContentRatioContainer Grid.Row="0">
            <Image Aspect="AspectFill" Source="KevingroveCarouselImg.png" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" x:Name="bigImg" />
        </ratio:ContentRatioContainer>

        <artina:Button Margin="10,10,10,10" x:Name="ImgZoom" Clicked="EnlargeImage" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" Image="IncreaseImageIcon.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent"  HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"/>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="#ede8db" Margin="0" Padding="30,0,30,0" x:Name="iconStack" >
            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static ratio:FontAwesome.WHEELCHAIR_ALT}" Style="{StaticResource FontIcon}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="30" />
            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static ratio:FontAwesome.CUTLERY}" Style="{StaticResource FontIcon}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="30" />
            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static ratio:FontAwesome.WIFI}" Style="{StaticResource FontIcon}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="30" />
            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static ratio:FontAwesome.CAMERA}" Style="{StaticResource FontIcon}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="30" />
            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static ratio:FontAwesome.MAP}" Style="{StaticResource FontIcon}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="30" />
            <!--<Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalOptions="End" Text="{x:Static ratio:FontAwesome.ARROW_DOWN}" Style="{StaticResource FontIcon}" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="30" />-->
            <artina:Button x:Name="openStack" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{x:Static ratio:FontAwesome.ARROW_DOWN}" 
                               Style="{StaticResource FontIcon}" BackgroundColor="Transparent"  HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Clicked="btnClicked" TextColor="Gray"/>

        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" x:Name="articleInfo" Padding="30,0,30,0">
            <StackLayout x:Name="TopLayout">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static ratio:FontAwesome.WHEELCHAIR_ALT}" Style="{StaticResource FontIcon}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="30" />
                    <Label Text="Address" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  />
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Have you tried to declare the stack layout with Labels as a first child in the grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which you add your elements in XAML matters, so if you want to have something at the top, just add it and the end in XAML. So firstly add row 1 and row 2, and then after it row 1 with your image.

Alternatively you can call [RaiseChild](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Layout.RaiseChild/p/Xamarin.Forms.View/) method on your container (grid) with the view you want to bring to the front as a parameter.

Comment: I think you can also do it with RaiseChild method, check out my edit.

Comment: RaiseChild did the trick nicely, I wasn't aware of that one, cheers