# xamarin forms - using RaiseChild in OnAppearing

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Leading on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49690510/xamarin-forms-slide-text-up-behind-image) I asked earlier, is it possible to have the ShowLess function run when the page opens so that the stack appears collapsed?

I tried to do it in OnAppearing but it did not work.

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            bigImg.Source = ImageHelper.SetImage(Convert.ToInt32(pageIndex));
            btnClicked();
        }

        public bool isIncreased = true;
        public void btnClicked()
        {
            if(isIncreased)
            {
                ShowLess();
            }
            else
            {
                ShowMore();
            }
        }

        public void ShowLess()
        {
            articleGrid.RaiseChild(imgContainer);
            TopLayout.TranslateTo(0, -(TopLayout.Bounds.Height + 60), 500, Easing.Linear);
            isIncreased = false;
        }

        public void ShowMore()
        {
            TopLayout.TranslateTo(0, 0, 500, Easing.Linear);
            isIncreased = true;
        }
```

Comment: what problem did you have with using ShowLess() in OnAppearing?

Comment: I can debug into the code, so it does run, it just does not appear to change anything on the page.  I know that doesn't give a lot to go on, I guess I'm asking is it ok to manipulate page elements in this way OnAppearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting Opacity to 0.0 in XAML for views which you don't want to see during page initialization and then (when user clicks the button) moving your "movable" views to initial position, setting opacity to 1.0 and starting the moving animation?